# Range.Cells.Count vs Range.Count

Tags: vba, excel

I've reworded my original question.

```
Sub s()
  Dim r As Range
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:D5")
  Debug.Print r.Rows.Count    'returns 4
  Debug.Print r.Columns.Count 'returns 3
  Debug.Print r.Cells.Count   'returns 12
  Debug.Print r.Count 'also returns 12
End Sub
```

In this particular scenario r.Cells.Count and r.Count are the same.  I've come across this in numerous publications, where `Cells` is the default item if none is specified.

I'm just wondering if anyone has come across any Microsoft documentation that actually states this - so far I haven't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't actually know what you *think* you know. :)

Depending on how you assign the range, `Range.Count` may return the number of rows or columns, not the number of cells; `Cells.Count` will always return the number of cells. To demonstrate, try this:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ActiveSheet.Columns(1)
    MsgBox "Cells count is: " & rg.Cells.Count & vbLf & "Count is: " & rg.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: "You don't actually know what you think you know." – I have no doubt that may be true a lot of the time, but in this particular case I do know what I think I know.:)  And I am aware that in your example Rg.Count is NOT the same as Rg.Cells.Count.  I obviously phrased my original question poorly, so I've reworded it, hopefully my intent is clearer this time.

Comment: @daveu Still the same issue though - `Cells` is clearly **not** *"the default if none is specified"* (as shown above, it depends how you created the range object) so I'd be worried if you could find documentation that says it is.

Comment: You're correct, and I agree that in your example "Cells" is not the default.  However, in my example "Cells" does appear to be the default, and I've seen it used that way in numerous examples.   Personally, I always do declare "Cells", just so there's no ambiguity.  I'm just surprised that Microsoft doesn't have much to say about this.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What I'm saying is that that is not the case. In your example, the range is essentially a collection of single-cell Range objects. In mine, it's a collection of columnar Ranges. The count just returns the count of whatever is in the collection - there is no additional implied property. Equally, a `For each` loop would operate differently in the two scenarios. Also, FWIW, it's probably safer these days to use `CountLarge` with cells.

Comment: I understand and agree with everything you've said.  And maybe my own personal use of the word "default" is not accurate in this instance.  I'm going to let it go at that.  Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 2):

In any situation, you need to ask yourself - what *namely* do I need? Number of cells? Of rows? Of columns? When you answer, then use appropriate actions:

1) Rows: `rng.Rows.Count`

2) Columns: `rng.Columns.Count`

3) Cells: `rng.Cells.Count`

As a tip, there's caveat with `Rows` property. If you want to iterate over rows and process their individual cells, then you **must** use `Cells` property of `Range`. Let's say, `A1` cell contains value `123` and you want to retrieve it.

```
Sub G()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim firstRow As Range
    Dim firstCell As Range

    Set rng = [A1:F10]
    Set firstRow = rng.Rows(1)

    Set firstCell = firstRow(1)
    '// DOES NOT WORK: Type mismatch
    MsgBox firstCell.Value

    Set firstCell = firstRow.Cells(1)
    '// WORKS OK! Shows: 123
    MsgBox firstCell.Value

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Also, when dealing with Range (especially in case of autofilter): the Range can contain non-contiguous range. The distinct contiguous ranges are located in `Areas` property, thus you will have to first iterate over Areas - and then process your range.

```
Sub G2
    Dim rng As Range, rngArea As Range, cell As Range
    For Each rngArea In rng.Areas
        For Each cell in rngArea.Cells '//or just "rngArea"
            '// Process further
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Play with this code to see what they really like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub s()
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

    Set rng = Range("B2:D5")
    Set rng2 = rng.cells
    Set rng3 = rng2.cells 'rng.cells.cells

    rng3.cells(1, 1).Select
    'rng2.cells(1, 1).Select
    'rng.cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Bottom line is, that both, `rng` and `rng.Cells` are `Range` objects referring to the same set of cells. Now, since `Range` has method `Count`, they both have, and obviously they would return exactly the same. The difference is that using `Range.Cells.Count` you accessing property of property of `Range` object.

Additional resources:

[Range.Cells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-cells-property-excel)

[Range.Count Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-count-property-excel)